# Suitable Regex Expression with ^ & $ for specific case

Tags: regex

There are two scenarios as below:

```
1234/12345

12345/1234
```

Client using a regex: `^\d{4}\/\d{4}$`
The above regex will not work due to the start and end characters being introduced.

Can someone suggest any modifications to `^\d{4}\/\d{4}$` regex which can extract the above values using start and end pattern i.e. `^` and `$` ?

Comment: What is the output you are looking for? What do you want to match?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You are matching for `d{4}/d{4}` yet your example has a d{4}/d{5} and a d{5}/d{4}....Or it is a single string "d{4}/d{5} d{5}/d{4}".

Comment: Edit your question and add test cases. Some strings that must match and some that must not.

Answer (score 0):

Leverage Regex range (`{,}`):

```
^\d{4,5}\/\d{4,5}$
```

- `\d{4,5}` matches 4 to 5 digits (`\d`)

Comment: You need to escape `/`.

Comment: Apologies, below is a better explanation:

For example 1: 12345/1234
I would like to extract 1234/1234 
if using \d{4}/\d{4} it will get me 2345/1234 

for this i need to use ^ to define the start position of the string.

Same is the case for 1234/12345

So I would like to extract 1234/1234 (first 4 characters from start of the string) for both examples on defining start and end position from the string.

Comment: @KarlReid: Why? It is not a special character in regex.

Comment: @Toto I guess some languages might treat it specially, otherwise I don't see any reason either...

Comment: Well, it's not strictly needed, but in many languages regexes are enclosed in `//` so you could prematurely end the expression(e.g., in JS : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags`), and all the online tools I have found for helping test regexes complain if you have unescaped `/`s. So it's not strictly needed but, why not.

Comment: @heemayl: The only case where you have to escape the slashes is when you have slash as delimiter. But in many languages you can use another delimiter.